# POWER BI set slicer default date FIRST MONTH of the year and END DATE current month year

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to make the StartDate of Slicer as 01/01/2022 this is the start of the year and I want to make the EndDate to 12/20/2022.

I have tried to use Between but I'm not achieving the expected result.

Below image is sample.

[image]

Expected result is startDate 1/1/2022 EndDate is Today 12/20/2022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CALENDAR` function.

```
CALENDAR (
    DATE ( 2022, 1, 1 ),
    TODAY ()
)
```

Comment: hi M.P. But I want that Date if it's 2018 it will automaticall goes to 2018

Comment: You can make a custom Date table using the CALENDAR function. And then make a relationship between your table and the Date table.

Comment: Do you have any video reference? as sample because it's hard for me to say it's correct. sorry pbi newbie here

Comment: I understand. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLupF1j49wo
Please take a look at the video.